# What is this object called?

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I have a matrix of the following form:

```
a=[[1 2 3 4]
[2 5 7 6]
[5 4 2 1]]
```

(for example).
Firstly, what are each of the elements called? ie. what type of object is [1 3 4] (a list without the commas). Secondly, how would I go about turning each of these 'things' into a list, so that the matrix reads:

```
b=[[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 5, 7, 6]
[5, 4, 2, 1]]
```

?

I started with a list of lists and then used insert to replace each list with a matrix of that list and it turned it into a. However, it was necessary for me to do so as I needed to keep lists in order and multiply by a matrix.
Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you using Numpy?

Comment: List without commas are syntactically wrong in Python. What does `type(a)` say on the first "matrix"?

Comment: type(a) says numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix - absolutely no idea what that means!

Comment: I have edited the question a little @RickardSjogren

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to a list? How something looks when its printed is not important - what is important is what is the datatype and is that what you want or not.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I hadn't made the distinction between the way something prints and it's datatype! I think my issue has been resolved now though, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object is a [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) and is converted to a list simply as:

```
as_list = a.tolist()
```

Comment: This is obviously part of a much longer code but it is looking like I could use this to help. I tried tolist before but I think I was trying it in the wrong way. Will let you know if this solves the problem! Thanks!

Comment: I had to use for and do this for each element of a as it does not work on the whole matrix. Anyway of doing this for each element (got that bit) but THEN replacing the current elements with their new list form, so the elements are all still in the same order within the matrix? So I've used for element in a: list_form=element.tolist() for the first bit

Answer (score 0):

As thefourtheye says, it's probably a [Numpy ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

Answer (score 0):

Following the insight from earlier answers, this quick demo might answer your question

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7, 6], [5, 4, 2, 1]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
   [2, 5, 7, 6],
   [5, 4, 2, 1]])
>>> print(a)
[[1 2 3 4]
 [2 5 7 6]
 [5 4 2 1]]

>>> b = list(a)
>>> print(b)
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([2, 5, 7, 6]), array([5, 4, 2, 1])]

>>> b = [list(e) for e in a]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7, 6], [5, 4, 2, 1]]
```

Thus '[1 3 4]' is called a numpy array.

-- revised for matrix --

```
>>> a = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7, 6], [5, 4, 2, 1]])
>>> a
matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4],
    [2, 5, 7, 6],
    [5, 4, 2, 1]])
>>> 
>>> print(a)
[[1 2 3 4]
 [2 5 7 6]
 [5 4 2 1]]
>>> a.tolist()
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7, 6], [5, 4, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: It was given in the comments that it is a `numpy.matrix` for which this solution doesn't work.

Comment: @RickardSjogren numpy matrix objects are a subclass of ndarray, so they inherit all the attributes and methods of ndarrays, and np.array is just a convenience function to create an ndarray.

Comment: There are some differences: `[list(e) for e in a]` gives `[[matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4]])], [matrix([[2, 5, 7, 6]])], [matrix([[5, 4, 2, 1]])]]` on a matrix, which is not what was requested.

Comment: Very well. Oversight for additional comments could be avoided if 'comments' doesn't need to a click to reveal.